# How do I use an external diff tool to compare *folders* in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, diff, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3, external-tools

I am attempting to use an external diff tool ([Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)) to compare **folders** in Intellij IDEA 13 (EAP Build #IU-133.471).

#### Settings

My Intellij IDEA settings are as follows:
[image]

#### Documentation

Relevant documentation for BC : [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs) and [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=11824)

Intellij IDEA's doc on the subject : [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-diff-tools.html)

#### Herein Lies the Rub

And here is what happens when I select two directories and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>  (the shortcut to `Compare Directories`) :
[image]

The same works fine when comparing files:
[image]

I have attempted using the current stable version of both Beyond Compare (v3.0) as well as Intellij to no avail. I have had no joy after appending the parameters `%1 %2` etc. to the `Path to Executable` either.

Can you think of what I might be missing ? Have you used an external diff tool to compare folders in Intellij IDEA ?

Am planning to ask this question in the Intellij forums and/or raise a Support Ticket with them after waiting to hear back from the SO community.

Thanks!

Update

Question now present in the Intellij IDEA forums too : http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5506980

Comment: Reproduces on my machine as well... I'd say it's a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Intellij.

See [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99225).

#### Update (9-Nov-2015)

I am using Intellij Idea v 14.1.5 and can confirm that this bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the IntelliJ plugin "Compare Directories" I have used it since IntelliJ 13.

Here's the plugin's home page: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=113

Once installed, the tool can be used by right clicking a directory or package and then setting the directory structure to compare against. This tool includes directory and file level comparisons.

[image]

[image]